# Ошибка при загрузке фото. В массиве $_FILES передается только переменная [name].

Tags: файлы, загрузка, php, изображения

Добрый вечер. Я уже спрашивала насчет загрузки фото, и мне очень помог Равнодушный, сказав что так как выводится:

```
Array ( [name] => tamada.gif [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 6 [size] => 0 )
```

значит, отсутствует временная папка на хостинге. На тестовом сервере все в порядке:

```
Array ( [name] => tamada.gif [type] => image/gif [tmp_name] => /tmp\php42E.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 14702 )
```

И правда, код обрабатывает только переменную [name], которая присутствует, и дальше не работает. Думала на хостинге решат этот вопрос, но они спрашивают у меня, где должна находиться временная папка tmp, так я сама понятия не имею. Где должна находиться временная папка на хостинге и как ее создать? Пробовала создать в корневой папке, в папке www, проблема не решилась. Какие еще могут быть причины отсутствия переменных: [type], [tmp_name], [size]? Спасибо. Очень жду ответов.

Comment: Добрый вечер! То есть у нас тут уже утро, вы наверное из Штатов? По поводу вашей проблемы: (1) вы уверены, что бекслэш в пути правильно обработается вашим сервером? (2) временную папку лучше создавать вне www, иначе она может случайно стать доступна всему миру (3) а почему не получается её создать? у вас есть ftp-доступ?

Comment: Никаких других причин. Только отсутствие временной папки [пруф]( http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php).  
Хостинг Вам предоставляется выделенный или виртуальный? То есть Вы арендуете весь сервер или нет?  
@vladD в от GMT+2 до GMT+8 сейчас вечер, а это Половина России и немного Европы :)

Comment: У меня вечер, я из Башкирии). VladD 1. Какой бекслеш, здесь, чтоли: /tmp\php42E.tmp? Так это имя автоматически у меня на компе создается. 2. Я им тоже говорила, что нужно создавать вне www, у меня на виртуальном сервере так же, они вот что ответили: "Не совсем понятно, как папку за пределами доменной зоны скрипт искать будет?" 3. В www и в корневой папке могу создать, вне не получается, выдается:"не имеете прав".
ReinRaus, нет, выделенный.

Comment: @Регина, подумайте о смене хостера :)  
Помимо отсутствия помощи по Вашей проблеме он еще и предлагает разместить папку загрузки временных файлов в пределах домена, что является просто ужасной уязвимостью, хотя настройка htaccess все спасёт- лучше так не делать.

Comment: ReinRaus, да, я тоже об этом подумала, но у меня, оплачено на 3 месяца вперед)

Comment: "Не совсем понятно, как папку за пределами доменной зоны скрипт искать будет?" Что им на это ответить?

Comment: Регина, не забывайте о преимуществе php. Скрипт выполняется на стороне сервера, это значит, что он может работать с файлами за дирекцией www =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер, как вариант, может вы забыли в форме прописать атрибут  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

**Дополнение №1**
Вот аналогичная ситуация [здесь](http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php/topic,228708.0.html)

Comment: нет, не забыла. на тестовом все отлично рабртает.

Comment: Дополнил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я рылась в инете, не нашла). Вернее находила что-то более менее понятное, были такие догадки). А у вас на хостинге какова структура?

Comment: Нема за что, у меня проще все как-то. По краем-меря проблем таких не было =)

Comment: Не тот хостинг, я думала они больше меня знают, оказалось, наоборот)))

Comment: Как бы, там сидят люди, какие больше отвечают за оборудование. Может 1 программист на компанию, который приходит не часто =)